# iTunes Connect re-add a test user?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, app-store-connect

I've been testing one of my apps awhile ago and ran into some inapp purchasing errors, so I decided to delete my test user and try with a new one. I wanted to add my old test user again to my account, but got this message:

> The following error(s) occurred: The email address you entered already
>   belongs to an existing Apple account. Please try again.

How can I fix this problem and add an old test user again in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't add an old user once more, even if you delete it. Just create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

From apple documentation:

> You can only create test user accounts using an iTunes Connect
>   accounts with the Admin or Technical role assigned to it. Test users
>   do not have access to iTunes Connect, but will be able to test in-app
>   purchases in a development environment on a registered test device.

[Link here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases_Robert/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html)